# Shorten Redis keys

Tags: .net, string, redis, encoding, stackexchange.redis

I have the following problem: I want to get a shorter version of some Redis keys. Part of the keys are strings that tend to repeat a lot. This set of repeating strings is limited.

Example:

- Some1.Repeating3.String3.<SomeMoreUniqueDomanin>.<SomeRemainingReallyUniqueDomain>
- Some2.Repeating2.String1.<SomeMoreUniqueDomanin>.<SomeRemainingReallyUniqueDomain>
- Some3.Repeating1.String2.<SomeMoreUniqueDomanin>.<SomeRemainingReallyUniqueDomain>
- Some3.Repeating1.String2.<SomeMoreUniqueDomanin>.<SomeRemainingReallyUniqueDomain>
- Some2.Repeating3.String1.<SomeMoreUniqueDomanin>.<SomeRemainingReallyUniqueDomain>
- Some1.Repeating1.String1.<SomeMoreUniqueDomanin>.<SomeRemainingReallyUniqueDomain>
- Some1.Repeating3.String3.<SomeMoreUniqueDomanin>.<SomeRemainingReallyUniqueDomain>
- Some2.Repeating3.String1.<SomeMoreUniqueDomanin>.<SomeRemainingReallyUniqueDomain>
- ...

I'd like to make the key shorter and was considering to hash part of it. For the first key, the hashed part would be Some1.Repeating3.String3.<SomeMoreUniqueDomanin>. Probably using SHA2.

After hashing, I get some bytes that I'd like to represent as string, so that I can concatenate with the remainder of the key. What encoding should I use when transforming this byte array back into string? I'm in a .NET environment, and I was thinking about using **Unicode**. Is that a good idea? **I want to minimize the memory used to store this key.**

Reading here and there, I came across places that mentioned about converting the byte array to a **Base64 representation**, but that makes the result longer in printed characters than the input.

I guess the real question here is that, even if Unicode generates fewer symbols when printed on the screen, is the space required to store them less than the space needed to store other encodings? Was reading Jon Skeet's [article](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Strings) and [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0) which seemed to suggest Unicode would be a safe bet.

--Just so I exclude this idea: getting rid of the first part of the key completely is not an option, as the "really unique part" is user provided, and this can lead to collisions.--

Other ideas or pointers?

Comment: Why not using GUID https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.newguid?view=net-7.0

Comment: Let's say the string is more reliable than the GUID. It's also passed by the user, but it's less of a chance there will be a copy/paste error, as there could be with a GUID.

Comment: provide copy and paste functionality to the key, or use the url of the web page as key if you have paginatgion. @cyan

Comment: "i need to generate easy to remember values" and "i need guaranteed uniqueness" are at odds with each other.  guid-collision is not impossible, but very difficult.  if you want a "middle ground" approach... then consider internet searches like "tinyurl in c#" or "random url in c#" or similar.  (Like, every time I need to "verify my streaming device with the channel provider"...those 4-8 string-length values.  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/201fc1/what-is-random-urls-and-how-to-creating-them-in-Asp-Net/      You don't need to keep the entire "solution", but the random string part.

Comment: Never said I needed easy to remember values. I just want them short, to save caching space.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using GUID. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.newguid?view=net-7.0.

provide copy and paste functionality to the key, or use the url of the web page as key if you have paginatgion